# Небольшая анимация

Tags: android, java, массивы

Добрый день. У меня возникла следующая проблема. Во время работы моего приложения в произвольном месте экрана должно происходить подобие взрыва, который представляет собой 9 картинок, которые должны быстро сменить друг друга. Как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вынести в отдельный поток функционал, отвечающий за расчеты по отрисовке взрыва. Но отрисовывать сам взрыв и всю остальную графику желательно в основном потоке. Сменять картинки(от 1 до 9) можно по таймеру, который в своем потоке будет менять R.ID текущего состояния взрыва(картинку).